# Unwanted zooming back to selected map pin

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mkmapview

I've got an issue with (I think) this mapView delegate method:

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
```

After I have selected the pin, it shows a a callout.

When I move the map so that the the pin and callout is out of sight (two or three screens away), or zoom on another area, then it zooms back to the selected pin.

I guess it's doing this because the pin is now out memory, and it is being re-created. In being recreated it is being selected and the view is zooming.

How do I get it not to zoom?

Anna K, below, asked for this method. I've also pasted the viewForAnnotation.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didSelectAnnotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view {

     if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]]) {
        // 
        NSLog(@"selected user loc");

    } else
    {

        selectedAnnotation = view.annotation;

        if (self.calloutAnnotation == nil) {
            self.calloutAnnotation = [[CalloutMapAnnotation alloc] initWithLatitude:view.annotation.coordinate.latitude
                                                                       andLongitude:view.annotation.coordinate.longitude];
        } else {
            self.calloutAnnotation.latitude = view.annotation.coordinate.latitude;
            self.calloutAnnotation.longitude = view.annotation.coordinate.longitude;
        }

        // this doesn't allow user to click away from selected pin to another
        // [self.mapView  addAnnotation:self.calloutAnnotation];
        // this fixes it
        [self.mapView performSelector:@selector(addAnnotation:) withObject:self.calloutAnnotation afterDelay:0.005];

        self.selectedAnnotationView = view;
        BasicMapAnnotationView *tempAnnView = (BasicMapAnnotationView *)view;
        selectedPin = tempAnnView.tag;


    }

}





- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation {

    originalRegion = self.mapView.region;
    if (annotation == self.calloutAnnotation) {

        NSPredicate *searchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"storeID == %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:selectedPin]];
        NSMutableArray* mutableFetchResults = [CoreDataHelper searchObjectsInContext:@"Store" :searchPredicate :@"storeName" :YES :self.managedObjectContext];

        if ([mutableFetchResults count] > 0)
        {
            Singleton *singleton = [Singleton sharedSingleton];
            Store *tempStore = (Store*)[mutableFetchResults objectAtIndex:0]; 
            if (tempStore.storeIsPicked == [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]) {
                singleton.isPicked = YES;
            } else
            {
                singleton.isPicked = NO;
            }

        }


            AccessorizedCalloutMapAnnotationView *calloutMapAnnotationView = [[[AccessorizedCalloutMapAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation: annotation reuseIdentifier: @"CalloutAnnotation"] autorelease];
    calloutMapAnnotationView.contentHeight = 40.0;


            if ([mutableFetchResults count] > 0)
            {

                Store *store = (Store*)[mutableFetchResults objectAtIndex:0];  

                UILabel *shopName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(36, -3, 250, 29)];
                shopName.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14.0];
                shopName.text = store.storeName;
                shopName.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];

                UILabel *addressName = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(36, 13, 250, 29)];
                addressName.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:9.0];
                addressName.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
                addressName.text = store.storeAddress;
                addressName.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];

                [calloutMapAnnotationView.contentView addSubview:shopName];
                [calloutMapAnnotationView.contentView addSubview:addressName];

                calloutMapAnnotationView.parentAnnotationView = self.selectedAnnotationView;

                [shopName release];
                [addressName release];
                calloutMapAnnotationView.mapView = self.mapView;
                return calloutMapAnnotationView;
            } else 
            {
                NSLog(@"returning nil .. no stores");
                return nil;
            }



    } 

    else 
    {

        if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[MKUserLocation class]])
        {
            // do something with blue dot?

        }
        else
        {

            BasicMapAnnotationView *annotationView = [[[BasicMapAnnotationView alloc] initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"CustomAnnotation"] autorelease];
            BasicMapAnnotation *tempAn = (BasicMapAnnotation *)annotation;



            if ([annotation isKindOfClass:[BasicMapAnnotation class]])
                {
                NSPredicate *searchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"storeID == %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:tempAn.mapTag]];

                NSMutableArray* mutableFetchResults = [CoreDataHelper searchObjectsInContext:@"Store" :searchPredicate :@"storeName" :YES :self.managedObjectContext];

                if ([mutableFetchResults count]>0)
                {
                    Store *store = [mutableFetchResults objectAtIndex:0];

                    BOOL isPicked = [store.storeIsPicked boolValue];
                    if (isPicked)
                    {
                        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pinPicked.png"];


                    } else  
                    {
                        annotationView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pinOff.png"];


                    }
                    annotationView.centerOffset = CGPointMake(-8, -9);
                    annotationView.canShowCallout = NO;
                    annotationView.tag = tempAn.mapTag;
                    return annotationView;
                } 
                } 
        }
    }


    return nil;
}
```

Comment: The map view wouldn't automatically change the region or center.  Find everywhere that the code changes the map's region, visibleMapRect, or centerCoordinate and see if it's getting called somehow.  Do you have code that executes when a pin is selected?

Comment: I believe it is changing the region because it gets selected when it gets recreated with viewForAnnotation. I could be wrong. It could also be that I'm not using dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier, but simply creating it..?

Comment: Your code is not changing the map's region, visibleMapRect, or centerCoordinate anywhere?  Post the code in viewForAnnotation and didSelectAnnotationView (if it's implemented).

Comment: I've updated my question with a couple of methods

Comment: Code is a bit convoluted and hard to follow but don't see anything posted that would obviously cause a region change.  In didSelectAnnotationView, note that addAnnotation is done even if only coordinate is changed.  By itself, not using dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier in viewForAnnotation shouldn't cause a region change either.

Comment: Suggest you implement regionWillChangeAnimated or regionDidChangeAnimated, put a breakpoint there before you select an annotation, and then look at the stack trace in the debugger (or type bt in the console) to see the sequence of method calls that lead up to the region change.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem in the past and the problem is that your map region is defined by the pins location. You should change the mapView setRegion code in your viewDidLoad method to your desired location, and then update if needed based on user location or whatever you desire.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];

// define span for map: how much area will be shown
MKCoordinateSpan span;
span.latitudeDelta = 0.002;
span.longitudeDelta = 0.002;

// define starting point for map
CLLocationCoordinate2D start;
start.latitude = 42.36873056998856; //Change to what you desire for starting point
start.longitude = -71.11504912376404; //Could also be set to user or pin Location if desired

// create region, consisting of span and location
MKCoordinateRegion region;
region.span = span;
region.center = start;

// move the map to our location
[self.mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```